# Data loader for a mounted drive on google colab

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, google-colaboratory, loader, drive

i'm using colab with a mounted google drive where i have a folder with 2000 images as dataset. I'm looking for a better way to load them because the following one takes so much time even for the first epoch. Thank you all :) .

```
def decode_img(img):
  img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img,channels=3)
  img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
  img = (img - 0.5)/0.5
  img = tf.image.resize(img, [IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE])
  if tf.random.uniform(()) > 0.5:
    img = tf.image.flip_left_right(img)
  img = tf.image.random_crop(img, size=[IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,3])
  return img

def process_path(file_path):
  img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
  img = decode_img(img)
  return img

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(data_path+'/*.jpg', shuffle = True)
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

Comment: Some sources claimed that google drive connector is pretty slow and suggested copying the data from google drive to colab:  
`!cp -r $data_path .`  
You could call data loading from there and it should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where the bottleneck was loading my images from Gdrive. If it fits, loading all your images to your colab disk should speed things up a lot. After uploading your data to colab this code will load it to disk.

```
!mkdir train_local
!unzip train.zip -d train_local
```